# Add or Delete Textbox Then Get Their Value Using PHP or Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What I want to do is to allow the users to have their choice whether to add more text box when filing their data.

So far I have this code

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.js

This is the code that I got.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .Delete{color:#ff0000;}
.Add {color:green;}
.Retrieve{color:blue;} 
  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function(){

    $('.Delete').live('click',function(e){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    $('.Add').live('click',function(e){
        $('.Option:last').after($('.Option:last').clone());
    });

    $('.Retrieve').live('click',function(e){
        $('.Option input').each(function(i,e){
        alert($(e).val()); //Alerts all values individually
        });
    });

});
});//]]>  

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class='Option'>
    <input type='text' name='txtTest'/>
    <input type='text' name='txtTest'/>
    <input type='text' name='txtTest'/>
    <span class='Delete'>Delete</span></div>

    <br/><br/>
    <span class='Add'>Add Option</span>
    <br/><br/>
    <span class='Retrieve'>Retrieve Values</span> 
</body>
</html>
```

That code allows me to add more text box and delete them, but my problem is I'm trying to get the value of those text box using PHP GET or PHP POST and if possible set some limit, maybe after adding 5 sets of text boxes the user will not be able to add more.

Comment: before add count the total options that you have, if is more than 4 then stop it if not add 1 new

Comment: Try using a form element with a submit button with either a get or post method to send the data as an action to a php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to post to PHP, simply wrap your HTML in a `form` element:

```
<form method="GET" action="myPage.php">
    <div class='Option'>
        <input type='text' name='txtTest'/>
        <input type='text' name='txtTest'/>
        ...
    </div>
</form>
```

Then to limit the number of `.Option` elements which can be added, simply declare a global variable which counts the number of `.Option` elements:

```
var optionCount = 1;

$('.Delete').live('click',function(e){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    optionCount--; /* Decrease optionCount. */
});

$('.Add').live('click',function(e){
    if (optionCount < 5) { /* Only if optionCount is less than 5... */
        $('.Option:last').after($('.Option:last').clone());
        optionCount++; /* Increase optionCount. */
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! Now my only problem is how to get it. :) Thanks James Donnelly!

Comment: Ahh, yeah. Thanks for your reply James Donnelly sorry co'z I forgot to say that my real problem is how to get the value of  the cloned one. If the user wants 9 textboxes, how do I able to output 9 boxes also?

Comment: Should I get the value with something like this?

<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];

echo "$a";
echo "$b";
echo "$c";
?>

Comment: To get `a`, `b` and `c` through `$_POST`, you'd have to change your form's `method` to "POST" and change your input names to "a", "b" and "c" respectively.

Comment: Yeah I already do that, but how do I get the value in the clone? what is their "name" so that I can able to call them? By the way thanks! I really appreciate you James

Answer (score 1):

You must check the number of inputs in the add event.
You use form tag to transfer data to server and 
you also must set "method" attribute in form tag with GET or POST

> ```
>     <html>
>     <body>
>     <head> 
> <script type='text/javascript'> $(function(){
>  $('.Add').live('click',function(e){
>        if($('.option input').length < 5)
>        {
>           $('.Option:last').after($('.Option input:last').val('').clone());
>        }
>           // Other code
>           // ...
>  }
>     });
> </script>
> </head>
>     <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
>     <input type='text' name='txtTest'/><br>
>     <input type='text' name='txtTest'/><br>
>     <input type="submit">
>     </form>
>
>     </body>
>     </html>
> ```

Comment: Thanks Buddy! Now I've set the limit of the textboxes. I'm having a problem on getting the value of a cloned textboxes. Should I do it like this?

<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];

echo "$a";
echo "$b";
echo "$c";
?>